# Can't include IDW interpolation in model using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am using QGIS 3.16.10.

I want to include the IDW interpolation in my graphical model but the IDW only accepts already existing layers (shapefile), but I want it to take the generated output.

Can this be done somehow?

I have a similar problem with the raster calculator.

Here a picture of my model:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to include IDW interpolation in a model of my own and found this post as a result of some Googling.

After some further reading I found that it is related to this issue.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30029

From the bug tracker notes it appears that the combo-box used to receive the input uses a custom parameter type which does not have modeler wrapper implemented. Until this is fixed this process will not be able to take a model input.